# linq expression as parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have to query collection like this:

```
myList.Where(s => myFilters.Contains(s.CountryCode))
```

`s.CountryCode` above is an example. I want to make it variable and call for different columns, like this:

```
myList.Where(s => myFilters.Contains(s.City))
myList.Where(s => myFilters.Contains(s.Region))
myList.Where(s => myFilters.Contains(s.Zipcode))
```

So I would like to define function where the column expression is a parameter. What is the signature of such function?

```
public void MySelect( ??? )
{
    myList.Where(s => myFilters.Contains(???);
}
```

`myList` is an `ObservableCollection`, and `myFilters` is `List<string>`

Comment: I think you should define the type of the variable.

Comment: It depends on `myFilters` data type. Please extend your question with this info.

Comment: @VadimMartynov I don't understand....why you need to know myfilters data type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this extension method in a static class:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereContains<T, TValue> (this IEnumerable<T> obj, IEnumerable<TValue> container, Func<T, TValue> propertyAccess)
{
    return obj.Where(o => container.Contains(propertyAccess(o)));
}
```

The way this extension method works is that it accepts a lambda function that resolves the property given an object of your type. So you just need to pass a simple lamba like `x => x.City` to it.

Since it’s completely generic and not specific to your one `myFilters` collection, you also need to pass it to the function. But that allows you to use this `WhereContains` for many other situations too.

Using it looks like this:

```
// Test is a class with two string properties `City` and `Region`
var myList = new List<Test>{
    new Test() { City = "asdf", Region = "fdsa" },
    new Test() { City = "foo", Region = "bar" },
    new Test() { City = "bar", Region = "baz" }
};

var myFilters = new List<string> { "asdf", "bar" };

myList.WhereContains(myFilters, x => x.City); // contains asdf/fdsa and bar/baz
myList.WhereContains(myFilters, x => x.Region); // contains foo/bar
```

Comment: This is way better than using reflection... +1

Comment: I used to skip generic methods thinking of its complex structure. 
good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection

```
 public void MySelect(string column)
 {
   var result  = myList.Where(s => myFilters.Contains(s.GetType().GetProperty(column)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can use the following approach which allows to specify either filter field or filter function:

```
var adresses = new List<Address>{
    new Address() { City = "ABC", Country = "USA" },
    new Address() { City = "BC", Country = "USA" },
    new Address() { City = "C", Country = "UK" }
};
var filterValues = new List<string> { "B", "UK", "U" };
//
var FilterContains = filterValues.@Specify((values, value) => values.Contains(value));
var FilterStartsWith = filterValues.@Specify((values, value) => values.Any(v => value.StartsWith(v)));
//
var AdressesByCity = adresses.@Specify(a => a.City);
var adressesByCitiesContains = AdressesByCity(filterValues, FilterContains); // B->{ABC;USA},{BC;USA}
var adressesByCitiesStartsWith = AdressesByCity(filterValues, FilterStartsWith);// B->{BC;USA}
//
var AdressesByCountry = adresses.@Specify(a => a.Country);
var adressesByCountriesContains = AdressesByCountry(filterValues, FilterContains);//U,UK-> {C;UK}
var adressesByCountriesStartsWith = AdressesByCountry(filterValues, FilterStartsWith); //U,UK->{ABC;USA},{BC;USA}{C;UK}
```

Here the `@Specify` extension methods are implemented as follows:

```
public static class @SpecifyExtension {
    public static Func<IEnumerable<V>, Func<IEnumerable<V>, V, bool>, IEnumerable<U>> @Specify<U, V>(this IEnumerable<U> source, Func<U, V> selector) {
        return (values, predicate) => source.Where(x => predicate(values, selector(x)));
    }
    public static Func<IEnumerable<TValue>, TValue, bool> @Specify<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> source, Func<IEnumerable<TValue>, TValue, bool> func) {
        return func; // for Type-inference only
    }
}
```